# Image Mask not working with CSS - SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to make an image mask like this using an SVG;

[image]

This is what I have right now;

```css
    body {background:#000;}
    .bg {position:relative;width:400px;}
    .bg img {width:400px}
    .mask {position:absolute;top:0;right:0;}
```

```html
    <div class="bg">
          <img src="http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/hotels/middle-east/united-arab-emirates/dubai/dukes-dubai-pool-xlarge.jpg">
          <div class="mask">
                <svg height="100%" width="100%"><polygon points="200,1 150,210 200,210" style="fill:#fff" /></svg>
          </div>
    </div>
```

But the SVG is not covering the right part of the image, it should be on the right side covering the whole height of the image.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: You have defined an image with a `width` of `400px` and with an unknown `height. In the mean time, you defined a `polygon` with coordintes that seems to refer to a zone with a `width`and a `height` of `210`. So, you have to "fix" the dimensions of your image and the coordinates of your `polygon` to make it work...

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ But then the polygon still doesn't extend the height to the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "fix" the size of your image (`width` and `height`), the size of your `svg` and you put the coordinates of your `polygon` with right coordinates, you'll have the correct result.

I've replaced the image with a 400x400 image.

```css
body {background:#000;}
.bg {position:relative;width:400px;}
.bg img {width:400px;height:400px}
.mask {position:absolute;top:0;right:0;}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
          <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/wiiu/images/5/5e/New-Super-Mario-Bros-Art-21-400x400.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20121029024830">
          <div class="mask">
                <svg height="400px" width="400px"><polygon points="400,0 300,400 400,400" style="fill:#fff" /></svg>
          </div>
    </div>
```